# No search results for Plone Dexterity type

Tags: plone, indexer, dexterity

I have created a new dexterity type, and the type is working nicely, and title turns up nicely in the Plone search results. However I need to index the rest of the fields aswell.

Following the Dexterity manual I have created an @indexer and catalog, and I can see in portal_catalog that the "varenummer" index is filled with the correct column data.

My problem is though that I cant search on a "Varenummer" in the plone search field.

Any ideas?

I have the following schema set up in vare.py

```
class IVare(form.Schema):
    """Leverandør type, som kan oprettes alle steder.
    """

    title = schema.TextLine(
            title=_(u"Varenavn"),
        )

    varenummer = schema.TextLine(
            title=_(u"Varenummer"),
        )

    stoerrelse = schema.TextLine(
            title=_(u"Størrelse"),
        )

    enhed = schema.TextLine(
            title=_(u"Enhed"),
        )

    pris = schema.TextLine(
            title=_(u"Pris"),
        )

@indexer(IVare)
def varenummerIndexer(obj):
    """Create a catalogue indexer, registered as an adapter, which can
    populate the ``start`` index with the film's start date.
    """
    return obj.varenummer
grok.global_adapter(varenummerIndexer, name="varenummer")
```

In catalog.xml I have defined:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<object name="portal_catalog" meta_type="Plone Catalog Tool">
    <index name="varenummer" meta_type="FieldIndex">
        <indexed_attr value="varenummer"/>
    </index>
    <column value="varenummer"/>
</object>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Plone search field only uses the `SearchableText` index.

This is a full text index that most types fill with the concatenated result (a string) of all fields that should be included in the results.

There is a [`collective.dexteritytextindexer` package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/collective.dexteritytextindexer) that makes filling the `SearchableText` index for dexterity types easier.

Add the behaviour from that package to your type:

```xml
 <property name="behaviors">
     <element value="collective.dexteritytextindexer.behavior.IDexterityTextIndexer" />
 </property>
```

then mark your `varenummer` field as part of the index:

```py
from collective import dexteritytextindexer


class IVare(form.Schema):
    """Leverandør type, som kan oprettes alle steder.
    """

    dexteritytextindexer.searchable('varenummer')
    varenummer = schema.TextLine(
            title=_(u"Varenummer"),
        )
```

Comment: The problem I have encountered with collective.dexterityindexer is that it doesn't index the title from my types.

Comment: @PeterB: You are not using the default behaviour for the title; add another `dexteritytextindexer.searchable('title')` line to your `IVare` definition.

Comment: ah mixed two articles together - that's why I didn't get the title index.

I was under the impression that collective.dexterityindexer didn't work with title - therefore I didn't even test it. It worked fine